# How to import android studio projects from GitHub?

Tags: android-studio, github, import

I'm encountering errors when attempting to import the [Kotlin-Bluetooth](https://github.com/appsinthesky/Kotlin-Bluetooth.git) project from GitHub. Is this a regular occurrence, or am I doing something wrong?

I have imported the file by hitting New>Project from Version Control... Then in the URL field, I paste the following link: https://github.com/appsinthesky/Kotlin-Bluetooth.git. After this, I am met with a list of errors. I've been attempting to fix them one by one, but the list doesn't seem to end.

Am I importing the project incorrectly, or must I continue trying to fix the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your method is correct.
You should now try to resolve the errors.

Currently Android Studio has been upgraded a lot, projects created with Android Studio in previous versions are not compatible with the current version. So errors do occur, but they can be resolved.